# How to proceed in selenium when you have locators with same properties on different pages

Tags: selenium

I have a page1  with  category consisting of 28 entries. ( The locators are identified using name  for all these 28 categories. These entries have properties of name something like Category_0, Category_1, .... .Category_27 )

Now when i select any of these 28 categories my page switches to that category and it displays the sub-category of the selected option on a new page.

Now i have  this problem ---- The Properties of subcategories on new page are also named with ( Category_0, Category_1, ... Category_X ). 
When i try to select any of these in selenium, it select the locator on Main page instead of current page.

I am very new to this, please help and ask for any information needed.

Comment: try to locate elements by xpath or css path, not just by name. It will help you.

Comment: Thanks Sujeesh for a qucik reply.  I don't want to use the Xpath throughout complete test.  Is there any other way around to solve this ???    Or can you share your views why actually this is happening.

Comment: Why do you not want to use XPath? Please do not say it is slow or brittle.  Xpath performance is comparable with CSS selectors in modern browsers and you can make XPath (or indeed CSS selectors) as brittle or as resilient as you want